# Would raw soy sauce marinated chicken be more salty when cooked the next day?

Tags: chicken, marinade, chinese-cuisine, soy

If I had unused soy sauce marinated chicken, would it be more salty when cooked the next day?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave it marinating overnight, definitely, as it will absorb more soy sauce. Otherwise, probably only a small amount saltier, if at all as nothing has been added.